# Error in Firebase iOS Codelab Chat App tutorial

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, chat

While building the Firebase tutorial app for iOS in Swift, I got stuck at page 8 in the instructions where we set up the app to allow users to Send Image Messages. It is likely either an error with the code shown in the tutorial, or with my frameworks not being connected properly, but I have updated the pod and cleaned and re-built the app, and still am getting this error for both times Constants.MessageFields.imageUrl are listed.

Code:

```
if let imageUrl = message[Constants.MessageFields.imageUrl] {
```

Error:

> "Type 'Constants.MessageFields' has no member 'imageUrl'"
>
> This is a fatal error and build always fails on this line.

Link to this page in the tutorial [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/#8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's missing in the Constants.swift file. Just add the following code to the MessageFields struct:

```
static let imageUrl = "imageUrl"
```